# Return top n average values by group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database of real estate transactions. In plain English, I'm trying to write a query to find the top most expensive N apartment buildings per city.

I have the following relevant fields:

```
Address
City
Sold Price
Sold Date
```

To solve, my assumption is that I need to take the average sold price by address and group by city with a limit of N and sort by avg price. To tease out which addresses are likely apartment buildings, one would expect a high count of transactions with the same address within a short period of time to be an apartment building (the addresses do not include unit #'s). So if XYZ address is included in N transactions within a defined time range, it would be assumed to be an apartment building.

Disclosure: I'm pretty green in SQL, so the research I've done thus far has left me a bit confused.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact brand of SQL you may need to look up some of the syntax, but this may work: (top 10 where 5 sales in date range)

```
 select top 10 address,city, soldCount from 

    (

    select 

    address, city, count(*) as soldCount, average(sold_price) as myAvg


    group by address, city
having soldCount > 5
    where sold_date between '2012-05-01' and '2012-05-15'
    ) mytable order by soldCount
```

Reference this site for more info on "top" in relation to Oracle, etc.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

You can probably do this all in one select but sometimes I use inner tables like this to seperate the logic.. the idea behind count(*) just means how many rows